# Find min and max angle of an ellipse in Python

Tags: python, max, sympy, ellipse

I have an equation, describing an ellipse. I want to use Python to find the minimum and maxium angle *theta* and length of the axis *Lc* of these ellipse for further calculations.
The parameters *Lc1*, *theta1*, etc. are the axis length for the respective angle.
I tried `sympy.solve` without success (the result didn´t make any sense) and are now trying `sympy.solveset`.

This is my current script. That is followed by further calculation which needs *theta*.

```
import math
import sympy as sym
from sympy import solve, Eq
from sympy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#define parameters 
#Lc modelled with matlab before
Lc1 = 0.67 / 1000
Lc2 = 0.36/ 1000
Lc3 = 0.7 / 1000

#orientation of the cut section
theta1 = 89  
theta2 = -35 
theta3 = 25 


#calculation from Beaudoin et al. (2016) and Ebner et al. (2010)

dL = ((Lc2 - Lc1)/(Lc3 - Lc1))

c = math.atan(- (((dL * (math.sin(2 * theta3) - math.sin(2 * theta1))) - (math.sin(2 * theta2) - math.sin(2* theta1)))/ ((dL * (math.cos(2 * theta3)  - math.cos(2 * theta1))) - (math.cos(2 * theta2) - math.cos(2 * theta1)))))

b = ((Lc2 - Lc1)/((math.sin(2 * theta2 + c)) - (math.sin(2 * theta1 + c))))

a = Lc1 - (b * math.sin(2 * theta1 + c))

print('Done calculating a, b and c')


##try to find theta at min and max Lc
#theta = sym.symbols('theta')
theta = var('theta')

#define eqation that give us our crossover length
Lc = Eq(a + b * sym.sin(2 * theta +c))

dLc = Eq(2 * b * sym.cos(2 * theta +c) + sym.sin(2 * theta + c))


print('Busy finding minimum and maximum.')
sol = solveset(dLc, theta)
sol

#now we have the derivation we can go find min and max of Lc
```

Using `solveset` I recieved no result so far, because python doesn´t stop running.
I am not sure, if I can get a reliable result with my current script or not. What is wrong? Is there a more efficient way? I´d be glad if anyone could help me!
Thx in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Since this equation has no symbolic parameters and has floating point coefficients I guess that you just want a numeric solution so you can use `nsolve`:

```
In [4]: nsolve(dLc, theta, 1.2)
Out[4]: 1.22165851958244
```

The initial guess (`1.2`) comes from looking at a plot of the function (`plot(dLc.lhs)`).

Note that your equation looks like this:

```
In [26]: dLc
Out[26]: sin(2⋅θ + 0.697151824925716) + 0.0011237899722686⋅cos(2⋅θ + 0.697151824925716) = 0
```

We can solve this in terms of arbitrary symbols rather than particular numbers:

```
In [27]: a, b = symbols('a, b', real=True)

In [28]: eq = sin(2*theta + a) + b*cos(2*theta + a)

In [29]: solve(eq, theta)
Out[29]: 
⎡          ⎛   ________    ⎞            ⎛   ________    ⎞⎤
⎢          ⎜  ╱  2         ⎟            ⎜  ╱  2         ⎟⎥
⎢  a       ⎜╲╱  b  + 1  - 1⎟    a       ⎜╲╱  b  + 1  + 1⎟⎥
⎢- ─ - atan⎜───────────────⎟, - ─ + atan⎜───────────────⎟⎥
⎣  2       ⎝       b       ⎠    2       ⎝       b       ⎠⎦
```

That gives two solutions one of which is negative and one positive. The other solutions come from adding multiples of `pi`.

Comment: Hi Oscar, thx a lot for your answer! 
The second part of your answer produces what I expected. The only thing: before changing a and b to symbols I copied them as `aa=a` and `bb=b`. This way I can reuse them later on as numerics. - I change this in my code above.

Comment: Oh,... I recognize, that the same problem I hav with `solve`occured: the minimum is not the minimum - it´s >Lc2, which should be not the case. Maybe it´s just a local, not a global minimum?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was much easier than I expected:
Having the ellipse-parameters a,b and c the maximum is simply `L_maximum = a+b` with the angle `theta = math.raidans(45) - c/2`
Plus: The imported angles theta1,... have to be converted to radians as well, with `math.radians()`